# Can't add a folder to favorite pane on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, favorites

I accidentally deleted a folder in `C:\users\[username]`

Now I can't add a folder to favorite on the left pane of My Computer.

How do I restore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by creating a folder "Links" in c:\users[your yourname].

Comment: This works, but unfortunately when you add a folder to the Favourites it is now named "The Folder - Shortcut", instead of just "The Folder". I though copying the correct `desktop.ini` file in there would work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Recycle Bin, find your folder, right-click and Restore?

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I already emptied it.